# Does GIL make the Python Interpreter single threaded or your python code single threaded

Tags: python, multithreading, cython, gil

So I have been reading about the GIL but I haven't been able to make a certain subtle distinction. Is the Python interpreter (C process) single threaded itself when it is holding the GIL or can the interpreter be multithreaded (utilizing multiple cores, not the Python threading notion) but can only interpret one user level python thread at a time.

I am thinking about this because I am wondering if a C extension written in Cython did not release the GIL but utilized multiple threads would those threads be able to run on different cores? It seems if the user python program was single threaded and called on the Cython code for some long running operation the Cython code could be run on multiple cores without releasing the GIL (assuming no python interaction). Would it only be important for the Cython code to release the GIL in case the Python code calling on it was multithreaded so that other Python threads could be executed in the meantime by the interpreter while the Cython operation is being run on other cores?

Answer (score 1):

The Global Interpreter Lock is just a lock. It's a lock that must be held to interact with almost every part of the CPython implementation machinery, including the C API, but it cannot do anything a lock cannot do.

The GIL will not automatically prevent parallel execution of threads that don't acquire the GIL. That means C extensions can run multiple threads in parallel, as long as those threads don't try to hold the GIL and don't do anything that needs the GIL.

On the other hand, the GIL will not automatically enable parallel execution of threads that don't need the GIL, if those threads try to hold the GIL anyway. In particular, if you want to write code in Cython that runs without the GIL, you have to [release the GIL explicitly](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#releasing-the-gil):

```
with nogil:
    ...
```

You can also mark a function as safe to call without the GIL by putting `nogil` in the function header:

```
cdef void my_gil_free_func(int spam) nogil:
    ...
```

Comment: If you don't free the GIL explicitly, but don't use any part of the CPython Machinery can the code run on multiple cores? I understand that while that code is running no other Python byte code will be interpreted but if the Python code is only using a single thread (Python thread) it wouldn't have any negative impact right? (Purely from an understanding point of view)

Comment: @HashBr0wn: If you hold a lock, but don't do anything that actually needs the lock, can someone else acquire the lock while you're holding it? No.

Comment: I am more asking about using multiple threads that don't need the lock, meaning it doesn't matter that one of them is holding the GIL because the others are just doing some raw computations and have nothing to do with it. Would those be scheduled to multiple cores?

Comment: @HashBr0wn: Why is one of them holding the GIL? The most likely case is that all of them tried to acquire it, and only one of them got it. The others cannot run until the first thread lets them. On the other hand, if only one of them tries to acquire the lock and the others just run without it, then they can run in parallel (but the first thread probably shouldn't be holding the lock).

Comment: No special GIL-specific knowledge is necessary to reach these conclusions. The GIL is just a lock.

Comment: Yeah I know there is no practical use case for the question. It's just purely for the sake of understanding. If python code called Cython code for some computation, and the Cython code used multiple threads to complete that computation (not using any part of the CPython machinery), but did not release the GIL those Cython threads would still be multicore right?

Comment: And just in the mean time if the Python code happened to be multithreaded then while the Cython code is doing the computation there would be a penalty of no other python threads running, but if the Python code is single threaded then it wouldn't matter?